# Use google tag manager install GA4 for SPA but the field page is not work

Tags: single-page-application, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I use Google Tag Manager to install GA4 for SPA (single page application).

I search a lot of articles about setting SPA and it seems like I need to add a page field.
I tried to put the value as below but not one succeeded. I used Google Tag Manager debug mode to check the page view event was hit.

- {New History Fragement}
- {Page Path}{New History Fragement}
- {Page Path}#{New History Fragement}
- constant like /testGTM
- custom javascript like below

  function() {
    return window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
  }

Even I put the constant like testGTM, I still can not see the data contain testGTM. The page view data is collected but the URL is not the same as I expected.

Did anyone meet the same problem? Or the field page doesn't work anymore.
Thank you.

[Sample Setting GA4 in Google Tag Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wy2q.png)

Comment: Facing the same problem, Upvoted your question to see if someone has any pointers.

Comment: @Prakhar Thank you. I also post the problem in the google forum. 

https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/86016527

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to solve this problem.

First, click 「event」->「All event」.

Second, click「custom definition management」.

Last, click 「create custom dimension」and enter "page" in the parameter name.

After the above instruction, we can get the "page" data as normal.

**How to Check**

There are 3 ways to check

1.Engagement -> Event -> + custom(event scope)

2.Engagement -> Event -> click each event -> see past 30mins event's parameters

3.Engagement -> Event -> click each event -> scroll down to see parameter

P.S. I use the Japanese version so maybe the translations are different.

[image: create custom dimension]